# define the column names in mysql select

Tags: mysql, select

I would like to define a select query where I can control the column names.

Like below, the column names are the same as the values I am selecting:

```
mysql> select "a", "b";


| a | b |

+--+--+

| a | b |


I want:

| X | Y |

+--+--+

| a | b |
```

Sorry if this is basic, I have search all around but haven't been able to formulate a good search describing what I want.

Comment: It's not clear what you wish

Answer (score 2):

With SQL you can use alias for almost all db obejcts.

In your case:

```
select "a" as X, "b" as Y from ....;
```